# Is there a influxdb timeseries amount limit?

Tags: influxdb

Hello somebody know or have experiences if is there a limit of amount timeserie in influxdb. I pretend one timeserie each day with same schema, for example timeserie_2014_12_19_wd5, because i see in influxdb is possible query with wildcards. wd5 mean weekday 5.

Is there any problem for scalibility / managment / performance?

I pretend later build some continuous queries with same pattern. Maybe each year i will have around 1000 timeseries. But i will can compact them

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

InfluxDB v0.8.x doesn't have hard limit on the number of series and I've seen it run with > 100K.  v0.9.0 is in development now, with goals of significant increases in scalability and throughput.